# Duplicate a tensor N times

Tags: tensorflow

I would like to duplicate the tf.eye(4) N times, but I dont know how to do it.
For example: tf.eye(4)

```
[[1., 0., 0., 0.],
 [0., 1., 0., 0.],
 [0., 0., 1., 0.],
 [0., 0., 0., 1.]]
```

I need to replicate these 4 tensors (4x4 Matrix) N times.

```
[[1., 0., 0., 0.],
[0., 1., 0., 0.],
[0., 0., 1., 0.],
[0., 0., 0., 1.],
[1., 0., 0., 0.],
[0., 1., 0., 0.],
[0., 0., 1., 0.],
[0., 0., 0., 1.],
[1., 0., 0., 0.],...
```

Any ideas how I can do this in tensorflow easily?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that using [tf.tile](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tile). You pass it a list of length equal to the number of dimensions in the tensor to be replicated. Each value in this list corresponds to how many times you want to replicate along the specific dimension. Here is an example:

```
# tesnosr of size [4, 4]
a = tf.constant([[1., 0., 0., 0.],
                 [0., 1., 0., 0.],
                 [0., 0., 1., 0.],
                 [0., 0., 0., 1.]],)

# replicate 2 times along first dimension
multiples = [2, 1]

b = tf.tile(a, multiples)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

print(sess.run(b))

# [[1. 0. 0. 0.]
#  [0. 1. 0. 0.]
#  [0. 0. 1. 0.]
#  [0. 0. 0. 1.]
#  [1. 0. 0. 0.]
#  [0. 1. 0. 0.]
#  [0. 0. 1. 0.]
#  [0. 0. 0. 1.]]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a straightforward application of `tf.tile`.

```
x = tf.eye(4)
y = tf.tile(x, [4,1])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    a, b = sess.run([x, y])

# a.shape = [4,4]
# b.shape = [16,4]
```